# How to start a windows service on local computer

Tags: windows, windows-services

I have created a windows service.

When I install msi, this service goes to local services, but doesn't start. When i try to start it, it gives this error:

```
    Windows could not start this service on Local computer.

    Error 1053: The service didnot respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
```

One more thing is, that when I install msi as a service, it goes to local services, but doesn't start and gives warning that you don't have privileges to start this service.

Comment: Are you sure you have admin privileges when starting the service?

Comment: @Iridio: Then it would be access denied error.

Comment: If using .NET then what version of the framework?

Comment: Can you post the code of the service? Are you starting a thread for the main method in the Start() method?

Comment: Does the service work if you install it manually?

Comment: Not nearly enough information. The service is buggy, but there are thousands of ways it can be buggy. Post some code, please.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have created the service, go to "Services", and find the service you just created.

Right click on the service name, and select Properties. Under Log On, make sure the service is using an account that has permissions to the machine and anything your service needs. The default account is a Local System account, which has access [to the following](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684190%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) .

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft has a couple of fixes to this problem [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839174) and [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/886695). They might help you.